# showing tree node details separately in the same window

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

How can I show the details of a tree node, upon selection, in the same window but separately from the hierarchy tree.
So far I have successfully showed details in the treeview class using this code:

```
  private void buttonCreateTree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (xd != null)
        {
            TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(xd.Root.FirstNode.ToString());
            AddNode(xd.Root, rootNode);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);

        }
        if (xd == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No saved XML file!");

        }
    }
```

I've read about tags, but since I'm not very fond of Windows Forms, I don't know how to implement them correctly. What is the correct syntax for the solution?
Update: The details of a tree node are its child components with custom attributes i made like creationDate, LastAccessDate and LastModifiedDate so it needs to show the child elements of a tree node in the same window but apart from the hierarchy tree? that doesn't even make sense O.o

Comment: Tags are used to store helpful stuff but they are never visible. Yo need to decide just what and how to show: One line of text, several, numbers, formatted? a table etc.. Even without selection, just by hovering over it you can show a ToolTip is you assign the values to each node. ´someNode.ToolTip = someText`.. If you want to show formatted details you should create a usercontrol that holds labels etc to show the data and has a function showTag(TreeNode aNodeWithData).

Comment: If the node contains the data use them, if they are too complex you could store the in the Tag (use a class maybe) and then cast the Tag to the data class.. - what details of the node do you want to show?

Comment: @TaW Well I am trying to show all the child elements of the node, the treeview is populated with the specified folder on my desktop, and the requirement is that when the parent node is selected it has to show all the child elements in the same window but separately from the hierarchy tree...that actually confuses me, is it possible?

Comment: To show the child nodes (in addition to them showing by expanding the node?) you need to crete a new tree with the node and its child nodes. each node can only reside in one place, so you need to copy/clone the nodes.. Can you make a sketch of the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want, or for that matter if you are but you can play with this:

Add a `Panel panel1` to the form and hook up this event:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Controls.Count == 0)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Add(new TreeView());
        panel1.Controls[0].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    TreeView tv = panel1.Controls[0] as TreeView;
    if (tv != null)
    {
        tv.Nodes.Clear();

        // option 1 deep copy:
        TreeNode tc = (TreeNode)e.Node.Clone();
        tv.Nodes.Add(tc);

        // option 2 shallow copy, 1 level
        TreeNode tn =  tv.Nodes.Add(e.Node.Text);
        foreach (TreeNode cn in e.Node.Nodes)
            tn.Nodes.Add(cn.Text);
    }
    tv.ExpandAll();
}
```

Do pick one of the two options and try..

[image]

Comment: Im gonna go for this, coz i couldnt find any other way of showing the details and child elements of the nodes, the only way i couldnt think of is through tooltips...this is good, Thanks